# How to edit a gem at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I'm using 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete' gem, but it doesn't have multi column search, but there is a fork that does it ( more details at: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/pull/95).

Now I need to deploy to Heroku but it will install the official gem. How can I edit it? Or if it's not possible, how can I import a gem to the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the fork by specifying the :git path in your Gemfile declaration

something like

```
gem "_GEM_NAME_", :git => "git://git/repository.git"
```

your other option would be to just vendor the gem inside your into a directory like `vendor/gems/_gem_name` and then you could use the :path option as well

```
gem "_GEM_NAME_", :path => "vendor/gems/_gem_name"
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that!